# Datatables Ellipsis renderer script not working fine

Tags: datatable

I have a datatable with 5 columns and the 4th column included entries that more than 50 charactors.

So essentially, the information in my column cell (4th) is too large and I want to reduce it.Then I want to get the 'show ALL', the information when if need. I used the following script to do this.

```
columnDefs: [ {
            targets: 4,
            render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                return type === 'display' && data.length > 50 ?
            data.substr( 0, 50 ) +'…' :
            data;
                }
            } ]
```

What did I forget in the code ? How would I do this? Can anyone help ?